# Build Android from Source - Add Prebuilt App with Shared Library

Tags: android, rom

i've build my own androidrom from source and modified a few things.
But now i wan't to add an prebuilt .apk to the project,
read that i should make an folder in /packages/apps/
and add the .apk and an Android.mk to it with following code

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := <folder name>
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_MODULE).apk
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

and the added the module to the in my case /device/sony/honami/full_honami.mk
when i now run brunch i get the error after some time that no rule for target ***
so i tried some changes but nothing works for me and i can't find something where there write something other than this ...

so i added the .apk to the /vendor/cm/prebuilts folder and in the *.mk where i found the other .apks where copyed to the device i added my app and run brunch without an error.

But when i now start the app, which is on the device, it crash. 
Via Logcat i found out that this apk have some .so files in it and that it can't find them.
This is because i only copied the app not the .so files in the lib directory. But i can't find some solution for my problem.
Should i now extract the .so file and copy it like the .apk to the path the app looks? or is there a better solution for doing this?

Cheers
Moritz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AOSP build system handles the shared libraries differently from Eclipse-ADT.

You will need to extract that .so from your apk and create an Android.mk to it.

To extract the .so, just unzip the apk and get it from `libs` folder.

Here is an example for the Android.mk to libfoo.so shared library:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

# prebuilt shared library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libfoo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libfoo.so
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .so
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT)/lib
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Comment: okay thanks :) so i have to extract each .so and make an mk for it :) 
if the .so is in an folder for example 
/lib/folder/*.so
is it enough to copy it to /system/lib/*.so
or must i copy it to /system/lub/folder/*.so ?

Comment: It's enough put it in /system/lib. Also realize that you can build multiple artifacts in one Android.mk. Just not forget to always call `include $(CLEAR_VARS)` before each artifact's block.

Comment: compile just finished 10 mins ago :) but works good ;) thank you for your fast help :)